# vscode use existing icon for unkown file type

Tags: visual-studio-code, icons, project

Is it possible to tell vscode to use a specific icon for a certain file extension that it doesn't recognize on a *per project* basis?

Example:

[image]

In this case I would like both files to use the sass icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a file association in your `settings.json`

```
  "files.associations": {
    "*.scss.src": "scss"
  }
```